# How to Read Custom Format that Looks Like JSON

Tags: javascript, json

When importing data from a file this is one of the results:

```
{
id: 1234,
name: "Store name",
street: "Street",
house_number: "19",
postal_code: "12346",
city: "Brussel",
country: "NL",
formatted_opening_times: {2=>[09:00 - 22:00] 4=>[09:00 - 22:00] 6=>[10:00 - 18:00] 1=>[09:00 - 22:00] 5=>[09:00 - 20:00] 3=>[09:00 - 22:00] 0=>[09:00 - 22:00]},
open_now: true
}
```

We are able to show the data, but have difficulty with the `formatted_opening_times`. We would like to show it like:

> Monday: 09:00 - 02:00
>   Tuesday: 09:00 - 22:00
>   ...

I have tried to parse the data in JSON and show the content:

```
var opening_times = JSON.parse(storeSpecs.data.formatted_opening_times);
var content = "Monday: " 
content += ${opening_times[0][2]}
```

But result in error console is saying

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1

Hope someone can help.

Comment: The snippet you pasted here is not a JSON. If you have access to the server, you should change the response of this API so that it sends a valid JSON.

Comment: The error says it all in this case. The string returned is not valid JSON and therefore will not parse correctly...

Comment: Sorry, the part of code that I showed was part of a bigger JSON result. I've edited the post and pasted more information of the result.

Comment: Still not  a json. "{2=>[09:00 - 22:00]" is not valid. Validates it here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @PieterSanders If the snippet you posted is part of a bigger result and this subsequence is not JSON, then your entire result is also not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not JSON.  A hack would be to replace the "=>" with ":" and the "[" or "]" with quotes.

```
var org = "{2=>[09:00 - 22:00] 4=>[09:00 - 22:00] 6=>[10:00 - 18:00] 1=>[09:00 - 22:00] 5=>[09:00 - 20:00] 3=>[09:00 - 22:00] 0=>[09:00 - 22:00]}"
var jsonStr = org.replace(/([0-9]+)=>/g, '"$1":')
                 .replace(/\[/g,'"')
                 .replace(/\]/g, '",')
                 .replace(/,\}$/, '}')
var res = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

Comment: Won't work with numbers greater than 9. To be fair, there is no way we can convert this format into JSON without having the actual specification - if there is one.

Comment: It worked with his original post, then he changed it on us, I agree it is a horrible solution, but so is not having try catch around a JSON parse in a Node.js process.  BTW, I am changing his numbers into strings with the replace regex `.replace(/([0-9])=>/g, '"$1":')`, so greater then 9 is not a problem.

Comment: Thank you, although I agree it's not the most clean solution, I am not in power to change the output of this 'JSON'. Your solution to replace and reformat the output fixed it for me.